# In Diablo 3, while in the cathedral, what can I do with a full inventory?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm in the cathedral in Diablo 3. There doesn't seem to be any way back to town, and the concept of a "town portal" seems to have been removed from the game.

But my inventory is full and I'm only on the first level of the cathedral - what can I do about it? I don't want to just leave things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a town portal in Diablo 3 that is unlocked when you find the Leoric's crown (I believe that is where you are headed)

You will have to continue and and chose what you will pick up until you unlock the town portal.

You could alternatively use any waypoint you encounter to travel back to town before that.

Answer (score 11):

There is still a concept of a town portal; you just haven't unlocked it yet.

Mundane items only sell for 2-4GP each, so you're probably safe to drop a few of those on the ground or ignore new ones you find until you reach the next waypoint. Waypoints are fairly common so you're not likely to have to wait long.

Comment: Blizzard has intentionally tuned the game so that it isn't really worthwhile to pick up white items to sell them, you'll be better off just focusing on gold and magic items.

Comment: Pretty much this, but don't start ignoring all white items as gems/artisan materials/etc are all white-named common items. Simply drop any white(common) weapons/armour you have.

Comment: White items have great value in crafting but later on you can farm the Act V battlegrounds for easy white material.

Answer (score 1):

You can come back for the items within a short amount of time.

[How long does dropped loot last?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66732/how-long-does-dropped-loot-last)

This question details the time it will stay on the ground while you go do other things elsewhere. Just don't change Acts or leave the game within that amount of time.