# In Diablo 3: Reaper of Souls, Do Dropped Items Vanish?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have found the rooms packed with Goblins a few times. It seems to me I am not really getting as much booty as I should and I am beginning to think that, drops might vanish after being left unattended and far from my location.

Is this true? If so, what are the thresholds?

Comment: Dropped items shouldn't vanish completely, but their nametags will dissappear from view after the default 10 seconds. So you may be missing somethings not because they vanish, but because their nametag is not hovering over the items anymore. If you hit alt they will show up for another 10 seconds.

Comment: Never found the exact durations, but they do depend on rarity. Gold piles and white items do vanish after a few minutes, maybe five - several times I've backtracked areas with only Magic and Rare items remaining on the floor. I vaguely remember someone posting that Set items and Legendaries do not expire ever, but I can not prove that claim.

Comment: @Brythan closely related but I wouldn't say duplicate. "Do they" and "After how long" doesn't call for the same answer even though the answer to the linked question implicitly answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

As [Virusboy notes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/202523/51171) the answer to your title question is yes.

The PC thresholds for Reaper of Souls are the same as given in the [accepted answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/66735/51171) to [How long does dropped loot last?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/66732/51171)

> Regular items and gold disappear after exactly 10 minutes.
> Magic items will disappear after 20 minutes.
> Rare, Set, Crafted, and Unique items will disappear after lying on the ground for 30 minutes.

Also, the [other answer notes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/66742/51171):

> Based on first-hand testing, low-quality (grey) items seem to despawn in about 5 minutes

and

> Do note, that if you're staring at the drops, they won't despawn, you need to be some minimum distance (1-3 screens) away.
>
> As with everything else in the world, leaving and rejoining the game will clean up all of the litter you've caused.

The last sentence is not entirely correct.  If you are in a shared game and drop an item that someone else can pick up (i.e. not Bound on Account), the item will still be there if you leave and rejoin quickly enough.  Only Bound on Account items disappear immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they do, however.  From experience on PC, they will last generally about ten minutes.  On console they only tend to last about 2-3 minutes.  Although the tag do disappear, pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> will light all of them up on PC.  Currently the Console has no <kbd>Alt</kbd> / <kbd>Shift</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keybind action.